# Recursive Method Not Returning Expected Results (JAVA)

Tags: java, recursion

I was assisting a student with a question about for loops, essentially you have 2 numbers x and y and you want to sum every value from x to y together to get a total. For example 5 to 10 would print 45 (5+6+7+8+9+10). While helping this person I decided to write the program recursively for some practice and noticed that my recursive method wasn't returning 45, instead it just keeps returning 5. If anyone could explain to me what's going on I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

```
public class forLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = calc(5,10);
        System.out.println(sum);


    }

    public static int calc(int num1, int num2) {

        int sum = calc(num1, num2, 0 );

        return sum;
    }

    public static int calc(int num1, int num2, int total) {


        if(num1 <= num2)
        {
            total += num1;
            num1++;
            System.out.println(num1);
            calc(num1, num2,total);
        }

        return total;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe do something with the output of the recursive calc call instead of discarding the return value?

Comment: @azurefrog oh my goodness, you're so right. Setting total = calc(...) fixed it.

Comment: You could also do `return calc(num1, num2,total);` inside the `if`.

Comment: @JimGarrison this has a constant-time solution, not even iterative. `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n + 1) / 2`.

Comment: Of course, but the issue for me is misapplication of recursion.  If you wanted to practice using a hammer would you think "Hmm, I'll drive some screws with this hammer for practice".

Comment: @OVOFan It's amazing what you don't see after you've been staring at something for too long... ;-)

Comment: @JimGarrisonI was just writing this to brush up on recursion. Something like Fibonacci numbers is taught recursively when the itterative method is better. I am not implementing this code into a large scale project.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence and factorial are examples of recursively defined problems that happen to have a faster iterative solution.  There's somewhat of an excuse for teaching recursion using them as they provide the opportunity to learn that recursion is powerful but must be used judicously.  The fact that every iterative problem can be solved using recursion does not mean it should be.  This, and "hmm, a text problem - I know, I'll use regexes".

Answer (score 0):

When calling recursively, assign the result to total. That's the mistake. Java is pass by value. So you have to assign the value to total.

```
if(num1 <= num2){
    total += num1;
    num1++;
    System.out.println(num1);
    total=calc(num1, num2,total);
 }
```

Or you can return directly instead of assigning to total.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with you code was mainly not doing any aggregation.. the value returned from

```
calc(num1, num2,total)
```

is never stored.

replace:

```
total += num1;
num1++;
System.out.println(num1);
calc(num1, num2,total);
```

with:

```
num1++;
System.out.println(num1);
total = num1 + calc(num1, num2 , total);
```

a much simpler solution would be:

```
public class forLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = calc(5,10);
        System.out.println(sum);


    }

    public static int calc(int num1, int num2) {

        if(num1 > num){ // break condition
            return 0;
        }

        // aggregation in a recursive manner
        return num1 + calc( num1+1 , num2);
    }
}
```